# Passing arguments using kwargs Python but maintaining type checking

Tags: python, mypy

I have a common pattern in Python that uses kwargs to pass-through some keys of an object to another function that takes a similar object with some added/removed keys. An example is taking a DTO, transforming it and writing it to a database.

```
class FooUpdateDTO:
  foo: str

class FooModel:
  foo: str
  bar: str

def foo(dto: FooUpdateDTO):
  model: FooModel = FooModel(bar="bar", **dto.dict())
  self.update(model)

def update(model: FooModel):
  # do things 
  pass
```

Now if there is a change in the model like below, I want to see a type error that I need to update `FooUpdateDTO`.

```
class FooModel:
  foo: int # <-- type changed
  bar: str
```

But I don't.

What is the best way to make this work without having to write out the arguments manually.

```
def foo(dto: FooUpdateDTO):
  # model: FooModel = FooModel(bar="bar", **dto.dict()) # short and clean
  model: FooModel = FooModel(bar="bar", foo=dto.foo) # long, verbose, and repetitive
  self.update(model)
```